# Best way to implement internationalization on API Rest

Tags: rest, api, internationalization, http-headers, multilingual

I'm building an API REST which I want to be multilanguage. I'm going for english and spanish at first and then I'll add more languages. I've tried to search for a good approach but I'm still not convinced at all. Should I go for an url parameter to specify the lang like url/api/en?, should I use http headers like accept-language? should i go for other approach?

Thanks in advance I want to see what's your opinion about this.